# Azure-storage-blob create_container fails in dockerized Django app

Tags: python-3.x, docker, django-views, azure-blob-storage

I have a django view which is supposed to accept POST requests with zipped file and upload them to an Azure storage blob container.

This view works on my local machine, but fails once it is containerized and deployed, both as a webapp on Azure cloud services and as a Docker container on my local machine.

At first I thought it was a permissions issue because:

Running the app locally 
- Sending the zipfile returns a 204 (successful)

- If I disconnect the VPN, sending the zipfile returns a 500
  I haven't figured out how to get a 500 from running it through azure.
- After adding a network rule, allowing my current ip address (which I removed afterward), sending the zipfile returns a 204 once more. However, I had to add the IP address to both the storage container and the database (because the API has to check the token).

Running the app in azure

- Sending the zipfile returns a 502
- Adding the IP address to both the storage container and the database still returns a 502
- Adding the entire range of IP addresses (azure web apps have multiple possible, and one virtual) does not change this.
  There is a third list of possible IP addresses associated with the app, but it's for premier apps. I don't think this applies, but I guess I can go back and check it to be sure.

Isolating the problem:
Despite receiving a 502, rather than any of the error codes I asked for, I've isolated the problem to line:

```py
block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
```

Without this line, I receive the appropriate error codes.
Running this line locally, in the REPL, I'm able to get a response, unless I leave the VPN, in which case, it says the request isn't authorized. Adding a network rule via the AZ CLI fixes this.

Furthermore,Googling pointed me to --default-action settings for storage container, as well as the aforementioned IP ideas. --default-action is either to allow or deny creation of containers by new/random IP addresses. 
Changing this setting to "allow"
Let's me create containers locally, off the VPN, without an explicit IP rule using line 120 in the REPL
Changing it back to "deny"
Disallows me to create a container locally, off the VPN using the line 120.
Throws an error.
Neither settings affects the 502 error from Azure
I thought it may be a timeout issue, because the 502 error only happens ever for this page. Therefore, it's not a gunicorn/server configuration error. So I added a timeout value to the block_blob_service object. This didn't help.

I finally loaded the container locally and ssh'ed into it to try to get more debugging output. It seems the View is getting into an authentication loop and crashing python.

Here's the view that is responsible for uploading:

```py
class ZipUpload(APIView):

    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    parser_classes = [FileUploadParser]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # Todo: add isAuthenticated check and response upon failure.
        try:
            try:
                # Create the container from the settings file (fluxdb_clinical/settings_test.py, or prod, depending on stack).
                account_name = settings.BLOCK_BLOB_SERVICE['account_name']
                account_key = settings.BLOCK_BLOB_SERVICE['account_key']
                block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key, socket_timeout=60)
                container_name = settings.BLOCK_BLOB_SERVICE['container_name']
                # this next line breaks on the azure web-app platform. I think the container/blob must be
                # IP restricted in some way, as this line works on my dev machine until I leave the VPN
                block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
                # Disable public access, restricting access to requests using keys.
                block_blob_service.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=None)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(e)
                return(Response(status=STATUS['container_creation_failure']))

            try:
                # Create a filename, using the timestamp to ensure unique names.
                # Do we need to make a way to name the file by the actual test name? Or should I use the token to look up the user
                # and make a name that way so we can sort zipfiles by user?
                now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
                filename = 'zipfile' + str(now) + '.zip'
            except:
                return(Response(status=STATUS['dunno why would be breaking shit']))


            try:
                file_obj = request.FILES['archive']
            except:
                return(Response(status=STATUS['archive_retrieval_failure']))


            try:
                zipp = file_obj.read()
                block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name, filename, zipp)
            except Exception as e:
                return(Response(status=STATUS['zip_write_failure']))

            return Response(status=STATUS['successful'])
        except Exception as e:
            return(Response(e))
```

If the issue was credentials or token auth related, I would expect the failures to occur regardless of where the app was running. Also, if I was instantiating the container wrong, I would expect it to fail everywhere.

Near as I can tell, the interaction between http requests (used by the method) and docker is causing the problem. However, I can open a python REPL in the docker container and run it there without problem.

Here's the output from the server running in the Docker container - which seems to indicate an authentication loop.

```
.
.
.
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 73 in put_file_into_storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 152 in doRollover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 72 in emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516 in callHandlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444 in _log
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1308 in info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 330 in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 693 in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 73 in put_file_into_storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 152 in doRollover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 72 in emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516 in callHandlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444 in _log
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1308 in info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 330 in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 693 in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 73 in put_file_into_storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 152 in doRollover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 72 in emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516 in callHandlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444 in _log
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1308 in info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 330 in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 693 in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 73 in put_file_into_storage

.
.
.

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 693 in create_container
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 73 in put_file_into_storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure_storage_logging/handlers.py", line 152 in doRollover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/handlers.py", line 72 in emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 865 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1516 in callHandlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1454 in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1444 in _log
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1308 in info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/common/storageclient.py", line 330 in _perform_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/baseblobservice.py", line 693 in create_container
  ...
[2019-11-01 21:47:57 +0000] [33] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 33
```

I've truncated the output with dotted linebreaks.

Any help is appreciated. This is my second time posting, I've tried to be thorough, but if I've left anything out, please let me know.

Thanks.

Edit: I found a solution.

My pipfile only included azure-storage-logging and azure-storage-blob. By installing the entire azure wheel (`pip install azure` then `pip freeze >> requirements.txt`) and it ran fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare the packages installed by `pip install azure-storage-logging azure-storage-blob` with the packages installed by `pip install azure` and remove these non-related package of `azure-storage` from `azure` packages to get the list, as the figure below.

[image]

I think you could try to only add these missing packages of the left list (excludes `azure`), it also will work fine for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a shot. I think it will work as well, because now that I think about it, when I built the requirements.txt file the first time, I just added the two modules, rather than exporting pip-freeze to the file.